# algorithm - divide folders to groups

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I am searching for an algorithm to find an optimal solution for the following problem:

> I have N folders with files in them.
>
> I want to arrange them into Y groups such that the difference in the
>   amount of files between the groups will be minimal.

For example:

- folder1: 1 file
- folder2: 1 file
- folder3: 4 files
- folder4: 7 files.

For 2 groups, the optimal solution is:

- Group1: folder1, folder2, folder3 (total 6 files)
- Group2: folder4 (total 7 files)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem you describe is [makespan minimization on identical parallel machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling), where `Y` is the number `m` of machines and the number of files in a folder constitute the processing time `p_i` for each `i in {1,...,n}` where `n` is the number of folders. The problem is known to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) but [several approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling#Major_results) have been found. Using the [three-field-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_theoretic_scheduling_problems), this problem is denoted as P||Cmax if `m` is part of the input and Pm||Cmax if `m` is a constant.